# How to Remove Root Element in C#/

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to XML & C#.
I want to remove root element without deleting child element.
XML file is strudctured as below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <dataroot generated="2013-07-06T20:26:48" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
     <MetaDataSection> 
       <Name>KR04</Name> 
       <XMLCreationDate>02.05.2013 9:52:41 </XMLCreationDate> 
       <Address>AUTOMATIC</Address> 
       <Age>22</Age> 
     </MetaDataSection> 
   </dataroot>
```

I want to root element "dataroot", so it should look like below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <MetaDataSection> 
       <Name>KR04</Name> 
       <XMLCreationDate>02.05.2013 9:52:41 </XMLCreationDate> 
       <Address>AUTOMATIC</Address> 
       <Age>22</Age> 
     </MetaDataSection>
```

Deleting child elements look like easy, but I don't know how to delete root element only.
Below is the code I've tried so far.

```
        XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlFile.Load("path to xml");

        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//dataroot");

        foreach (XmlElement element in nodes)
        {
            element.RemoveAll();
        }
```

Is there a way to remove root element only? without deleting child elements?
Thank you in advnace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than trying to actually remove the root element from an existing object, it looks like the underlying aim is to save (or at least access) the first child element of the root element.

The simplest way to do this is with LINQ to XML - something like this:

```
XDocument input = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
XElement firstChild = input.Root.Elements().First();
XDocument output = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                                 firstChild);
output.Save("output.xml");
```

Or if you don't need the XML declaration:

```
XDocument input = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
XElement firstChild = input.Root.Elements().First();
firstChild.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I used below one and it worked perfectly. How could this be so simple like this!? Above code works like taking the first child and saving it without root element? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Toykeat: Exactly as you say - it just saves the element. No need to remove anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet What if I have many children under the same root element? should I use something like: `var allChildrens = input.Root.Elements();` ?

Comment: @YairNevet: Well you'd need to decide what you wanted to do with the different elements - save them to different files, or something else. If you're in a similar situation, I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: The 2nd snippet (`XElement.Save()`) will also include an XML declaration. So only when you need to control it precisely you need to create the XDocument wrapper.

Comment: This code doesn't remove the root. It simply returns the first child.

Comment: @TempoClick: It addressed what the OP actually needed to do, which was to save the first child as a new file. I'll edit the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to do in c# coding means

**Solution**

```
 foreach (XElement item in Element.Descendants("dataroot").ToList())
        {
            item.ReplaceWith(item.Nodes());
        }
```