# how to delete root tag in xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

hi following XML is my input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <units xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/common" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani512-input-CAR.xsd">
<unit type="journal" xmlns="">
<unit-info>
  <timestamp>2017-01-08T02:03:14Z</timestamp>
  <order-id>12535892</order-id>
  <parcel-id>none</parcel-id>
  <unit-id>4756202</unit-id>
</unit-info>
<unit-content>
  <bibrecord>
    <item-info>
      <status state="new" stage="S300" />
    </item-info>
    <head>
      <citation-info>
        <citation-type code="jo" />
        <citation-language xmllang="ENG" />
        <abstract-language xmllang="ENG" />
        <author-keywords>
          <author-keyword>Stroke</author-keyword>
          <author-keyword> cerebral ischaemia</author-keyword>
          <author-keyword> Neuro-protection</author-keyword>
          <author-keyword> Neuro-protective agents</author-keyword>
        </author-keywords>
      </citation-info>
      <citation-title xmllang="ENG" original="y">
        <titletext>PATHOGENESIS AND NEURO-PROTECTIVE AGENTS OF STROKE</titletext>
      </citation-title>
      <abstracts>
        <abstract>
          <cepara>ABSTRACT: Stroke remains worlds second leading cause of mortality; and globally most frequent cause of long-lasting disabilities. The ischaemic pathophysiologic cascade leading to neuronal damage consists of peri-infarct depolarization, excitotoxicity, inflammation, oxidative stress, and apoptosis. Despite plethora of experimental evidences and advancement into the development of treatments, clinical treatment of acute stroke still remains challenging. Neuro-protective agents, as novel therapeutic strategy confer neuro-protection by targeting the pathophysiologic mechanism of stroke. The aim of this review is discussion of summary of the literature on stroke pathophysiology, current preclinical research findings of neuroprotective agents in stroke and possible factors that were responsible for the failure of these agents to translate in human stroke therapies.</cepara>
        </abstract>
      </abstracts>
      <correspondence>
        <person>
          <ceinitials>M.</ceinitials>
          <cesurname>Mubarak</cesurname>
        </person>
        <affiliation>
          <organization> Bayero University Kano</organization>
          <organization> Nigeria. Email: mubarakmahmad@yahoo.com</organization>
        </affiliation>
      </correspondence>
      <root>
        <author Seq="0">
          <Inital>A.El</Inital>
          <Surname>Khattabi</Surname>
          <Givenname>Abdelkrim</Givenname>
        </author>
      </root>
    </head>
  </bibrecord>
</unit-content>
```

from this xml i need to delete root tag alone but i need all child element

```
        <author Seq="0">
          <Inital>A.El</Inital>
          <Surname>Khattabi</Surname>
          <Givenname>Abdelkrim</Givenname>
        </author>
```

how to delete root tag alone. For this i followed following code

```
  XDocument CarXML = new XDocument();
        CarXML.Add(Root);
        CarXML.Descendants("root").Remove();
        CarXML.Save(@"CAR.XML");
```

But this code delete all xml tag. How to delete root element alone.  i need child element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Root Element in C#/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503619/how-to-remove-root-element-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
CarXML.ReplaceNodes(CarXML.Descendants("author").FirstOrDefault());
```

This replaces the whole content of the XML with the first descendant named `author`.