# how to delete second root element alone but i need that child

Tags: c#, xml

Following xml is **my input**.

```
<units>
  <author-group>
    <root>
      <author Seq="1">
        <initials>J.</initials>
        <surname>Kim</surname>
        <given-name>Jiyeon</given-name>
      </author>
      <author Seq="2">
        <initials>k.</initials>
        <surname>Kim</surname>
        <given-name>ki</given-name>
      </author>
    </root>
  </author-group>
</units>
```

Here I need to remove tag only but I need that root tag child element.

**my final xml** like following xml.

```
<units>
  <author-group>
    <author Seq="1">
      <initials>J.</initials>
      <surname>Kim</surname>
      <given-name>Jiyeon</given-name>
    </author>
    <author Seq="2">
      <initials>k.</initials>
      <surname>Kim</surname>
      <given-name>ki</given-name>
    </author>
  </author-group>
</units>
```

For that I refereed below question. [How to Remove Root Element in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503619/how-to-remove-root-element-in-c)

and i tried code like below.

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(author);                    
XElement firstChild = document.Root.Elements().First();
XDocument output = new XDocument(firstChild);
```

But that root element did't remove. Is there a way other way to remove root element only? without deleting child elements?

Comment: Your final xml is NOT a valid xml. You may either remove the first `<root>` or the last `</author-group>` ... and assume the xml is not complete.

Comment: Just by naming an element `<root>` it does not become the root. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)

Comment: yes after deleted root i will add another root for that author-group element

Answer (score 1):

```
const string xml = @"<units>
                <author-group>
                <root>
                    <author Seq=""1"">
                    <initials>J.</initials>
                    <surname>Kim</surname>
                    <given-name>Jiyeon</given-name>
                    </author>
                    <author Seq=""2"">
                    <initials>k.</initials>
                    <surname>Kim</surname>
                    <given-name>ki</given-name>
                    </author>
                </root>
                </author-group>
            </units>";

const string elementToRemove = "root";
const string addElementsInElement = "author-group";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var matchingElement = doc
                        .Descendants()
                        .First(e => e.Element(elementToRemove) != null);

var innerElements = matchingElement.Elements().Elements().ToList();

doc
    .Descendants()
    .First(e => e.Element(elementToRemove) != null)
    .RemoveNodes();

doc
    .Descendants()
    .First(e => e.Element(addElementsInElement) != null)
    .Element(addElementsInElement)
    .Add(innerElements);
```

Comment: i got Sequence contains no matching element exception

Comment: I checked again and i don't get any exception. maybe you change the some values ?! Any way please this .cs file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Bt3nG4vreTWl9VVlBxQjZESUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code

```
document.Root // this will point at the <author-group> element

Elements() // this will point at the <root> element
```

So, when you call First() you are asking for the first  element.
I think you need to then call

```
firstChild.Elements()
```

This should then contain all of the  elements